# Php doctrine выбрать с максимальным рейтингом

Tags: laravel, symfony2, doctrine2

Есть организации которые имеют поля. Надо выбрать все организации и их поля у которых найбольшый рейтинг.

```
SELECT fd.id, fd.organisation_id, fd.value, rating_finder.rating
                FROM field_datas AS fd

                JOIN (
                    SELECT MAX(rating) rating, organisation_id
                    FROM field_datas
                    GROUP BY organisation_id

                ) rating_finder 
                    ON fd.organisation_id = rating_finder.organisation_id 
                    AND fd.rating = rating_finder.rating
```

Как можно такое сделать используя query builder? Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно вам поможет данный ответ - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18120728/1714208